# Display json data formed from PHP in table using angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

Im fetching data from mysql db and putting it in json format.

fetch.php file:

[image]

echo $json; outputs the below to the console.

```
[{"id":"1","emp_no":"1111","first_name":"1fname","last_name":"1lname","dept_name":"1dept"},{"id":"2","emp_no":"2222","first_name":"2fname","last_name":"2lname","dept_name":"2dept"},{"id":"3","emp_no":"3333","first_name":"3fname","last_name":"3lname","dept_name":"3dept"},{"id":"4","emp_no":"4444","first_name":"4fname","last_name":"4lname","dept_name":"4dept"},{"id":"5","emp_no":"5555","first_name":"5fname","last_name":"5lname","dept_name":"5dept"},{"id":"6","emp_no":"6666","first_name":"6fname","last_name":"6lname","dept_name":"6dept"},{"id":"7","emp_no":"7777","first_name":"7fname","last_name":"7lname","dept_name":"7dept"},{"id":"8","emp_no":"8888","first_name":"8fname","last_name":"8lname","dept_name":"8dept"},{"id":"9","emp_no":"9999","first_name":"9fname","last_name":"9lname","dept_name":"9dept"}]
```

My controller looks like this:

```
.controller('fetchController', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get("fetch.php")
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.user = data;
        console.log($scope.user);
    });
```

$scope.user = data.data; Some suggested this but I get an undefined when I console.log($scope.user);

When $scope.user = data; console.log($scope.user); shows the same json output as above.

[image]

I then want to put this into my html table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Depart</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in user track by $index">
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.emp_no}}</td>
    <td>{{x.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.dept_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

But im getting no data returned to my page... Data is returned when I hardcode some json data but not when reading from the PHP query. Any ideas why?

```
.controller('fetchController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("fetch.php")
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.user = [{
                "id": "1",
                "emp_no": "1111",
                "first_name": "1fname",
                "last_name": "1lname",
                "dept_name": "1dept"
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "emp_no": "2222",
                "first_name": "2fname",
                "last_name": "2lname",
                "dept_name": "2dept"
            }];
            console.log($scope.user);
        });
```

Returns:

[image: page when json hardcoded]

Edit: Ive added more detail to the post so hopefully someone can see where the problem lies.

Comment: Have you tried $scope.user = data.data. See the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http - "The response object has these properties: ...".

Comment: $scope.user = data.data gives me an undefined when i try print it to console... console.log(data) shows the json so it looks like the controller is working ok. Im no expert so could be missing something small or even completely doing it wrong :P

Comment: Does it work if you manually populate your users variable with data?

Comment: YES :) Getting closer. So theres some problem with the way $scope.users = data is storing my json? Or the way im linking to it in my html?

Comment: You are linking to html in correct way but may there is issue in creating json or in $scope.user = data; And $scope.user = data.data should be give you data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your "connected to db" output. You must remove that line from your PHP file and the rest should work as expected.

`echo $json` looked good because it is valid json, but since you had previously output text in your PHP script, the JSON decoding in Angular is breaking. If you look at the output you posted from the console, you see the "connected to db" text prefixing the JSON that you want in your application. That text prefix forces the output from PHP to be invalid.